# 2d Array column slicing in Pure Python without for loops

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, slice

Is it possible to slice a column off a 2d array in pure Python without a for loop or list comprehension? Say for instance you have a 4x4 array of ints:

```
grid = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]
```

and let's say you'd like to return the grid without the first row and the last column `[[5,6,7],[9,10,11],[13,14,15]]`
Is there a slicing syntax that allows you to do this? Excluding the first row is easily achieved with  `grid = grid[1:4]`
However doing something like `grid = grid[1:4][0:2]` seems like it should work but results in `[[5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]`. If at all possible, I'd like to avoid having to iterate through it in a for loop/list comprehension. I know that would work, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant syntax.

Comment: And yes, I'm aware that I would technically need grid[1:4][0:3] if that did work. I just used [0:2] to show that that's still slicing the first layer of the nested list, rather than the second like I want.

Comment: There isn't a way to do this in pure Python without iteration.

Comment: Curious what you would consider more elegant than `[row[:-1] for row in x[1:]]` anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ddejohn's point, this can't be done with just slicing notation. This doesn't use slicing notation but a good answer that doesn't use list comps or for loops is list(zip(*matrix)) if matrix is the input list.